# display images in emacs w3m in terminal

Tags: terminal-emacs, images, web-browser, w3m

I would like w3m in emacs (in a terminal) to show me pictures.

Showing pictures in emacs gui works:
[image: images in emacs gui without terminal]

Showing pictures in the terminal without emacs works:
[image: images in w3m without emacs]

But in emacs w3m running in a terminal, no images are shown:
[image: no images in w3m in emacs in terminal]

Pressing T doesn't help, instead I get the message "Can't display images in this environment".

But since emacs and termite are clearly able to show images from w3m, why not at the same time?

Additional information: I am using x86_64 Arch Linux 4.7 with GNU Emacs 24.5.1 and w3m 0.5.3 and the w3m package 20160727.837 in emacs

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: "But since emacs and termite are clearly able to show images from w3m, why not at the same time?" - Or in other words: What can I do to make it work?

Comment: This is a terrible hack that relies on a xterm-compatible terminal emulator and a working framebuffer.  I wouldn't expect it to ever work under Emacs and its w3m package.

Comment: Some would say it is beautifull. But honestly, I have no idea how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From elisp [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Images.html#Images):

> Emacs is usually able to display images when it is run on a graphical terminal. Images cannot be displayed in a text terminal, on certain graphical terminals that lack the support for this, or if Emacs is compiled without image support.

So the answer is no.